# How make action after redux state update?

Tags: redux, react-redux

i'm working with redux and have simple probleme. How make action after redux update state. For example i have this code.

```
import {
  ADD_TO_CART,
  ADD_QUANTITY,
  SUB_QUANTITY,
  REMOVE_FROM_CART,
  EMPTY_CART,
  UPDATE_PRICE
} from '../actions/actions-types/aside-actions'
let cartInStorage = localStorage.getItem('cart')
let cartInStorageObject = JSON.parse(cartInStorage)
const initialState = {
  cart: cartInStorageObject ||  [],
  totalPrice: 0
}

export default function asideReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  let cart = state.cart
  let cartStringify = JSON.stringify(cart) 
  localStorage.setItem('cart', cartStringify)

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      let itemInCart = cart.find(item => item.product._id == action.payload.product._id)
      return{ 
        ...state // Example return
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I need save to localstorage date to cart, but function localstorage.setItem is before action and in localstorage not save last state.
How save to localstorage only redux last state update?
Thanks very much

Comment: This is likely a good case for redux middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useSelector` to get state and `useEffect` to watch this state and dispatch te new action:

```js
const reducerState = useSelector(state => state.reducerState)

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(newAction)
}, [reducerState])
```